# Scripts/tags getting removed in text when using antisamy.jar/xml

Tags: java, javascript, antisamy

I am using antisamy.xml and antisamy.jar for preventing XSS.
So when i enter a script tag in the text box it truncates it and the other text apart from the tag is stored in the database.

I want to store the script/tag in the database too, but without applying the script/tag.

For example,
If i enter alert(); in the text box on the jsp page.
I want the whole thing saved in db but i should not get the alert on ui.